# Redux-persist does not work with Redux-Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The app works fine The only thing is that redux persist is not working as it should.Persist doest not persist anything,it does not give any errors in the console(in VSC or in Chrome) so I have zero information about where it is failing.Any ideas? thanks for your time and sorry for my bad english

This is the App.js

```js
import FuseAuthorization from '@fuse/core/FuseAuthorization';
import FuseLayout from '@fuse/core/FuseLayout';
import FuseTheme from '@fuse/core/FuseTheme';
import history from '@history';
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset, StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import { create } from 'jss';
import jssExtend from 'jss-plugin-extend';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import Provider from 'react-redux/es/components/Provider';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import AppContext from './AppContext';
import { Auth } from './auth';
import routes from './fuse-configs/routesConfig';
import {store persistor} from './store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
const jss = create({
    ...jssPreset(),
    plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, jssExtend(), rtl()],
    insertionPoint: document.getElementById('jss-insertion-point')
});

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({ disableGlobal: true });
const App = () => {
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                routes
            }}
        >
            <StylesProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <PersistGate  persistor={persistor}>
                        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                            <Auth>
                                <Router history={history}>
                                    <FuseAuthorization>
                                        <FuseTheme>
                                            <SnackbarProvider
                                                maxSnack={5}
                                                anchorOrigin={{
                                                    vertical: 'bottom',
                                                    horizontal: 'right'
                                                }}
                                                classes={{
                                                    containerRoot: 'bottom-0 right-0 mb-52 md:mb-68 mr-8 lg:mr-80 z-99'
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <FuseLayout />
                                            </SnackbarProvider>
                                        </FuseTheme>
                                    </FuseAuthorization>
                                </Router>
                            </Auth>
                        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                    </PersistGate>
                </Provider>
            </StylesProvider>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

This is where the store is created:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import createReducer from './rootReducer';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./rootReducer', () => {
        const newRootReducer = require('./rootReducer').default;
        store.replaceReducer(newRootReducer.createReducer());
    });
}

const middlewares = [];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const { createLogger } = require(`redux-logger`);
    const logger = createLogger({ collapsed: (getState, action, logEntry) => !logEntry.error });

    middlewares.push(logger);
}
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, createReducer());
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            immutableCheck: false,
            serializableCheck: false
        }).concat(middlewares),
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
});

store.asyncReducers = {};

export const injectReducer = (key, reducer) => {
    if (store.asyncReducers[key]) {
        return false;
    }
    store.asyncReducers[key] = reducer;
    store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers));
    return store;
};
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

This is the createReducer():

```
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import auth from 'app/auth/store';
import fuse from './fuse';
import i18n from './i18nSlice';

const createReducer = asyncReducers => (state, action) => {
    const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
        auth,
        fuse,
        i18n,
        ...asyncReducers
    });

    /*
    Reset the redux store when user logged out
     */
    if (action.type === 'auth/user/userLoggedOut') {
        state = undefined;
    }

    return combinedReducer(state, action);
};

export default createReducer;
```

Comment: Now I move the persistor to the createReducer file,then I exported it from there. 
Now the app is working fine,but is does not persist anything.